# Setting date to firestore on google auth upon sign in with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-authentication

I am trying to set a login date on firestore upon sign in with firebase google auth but somehow it is deleting all user data and storing the date only with and without merge: true.

```
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

const GoogleSignIn = async () => {
  await firebase
   .auth()
   .signInWithPopup(provider)
   .then((user) => {
      firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.user.uid)
        .set(
          {
            lastLoginAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          }, {merge: true})  
    })
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `update` instead of `set`?

Comment: yes, update does the same it only stores the login date and overwrites the existing data. Dong this on normal email auth works fine but with google auth it behaves differently. I'm using Firebase v7.17.2

Comment: I have tested `set` method and its working fine. Do you mean that this is working fine when you use other provider?

Comment: yes, it's working fine with the email and password auth.

Comment: I re installed the the package and now it's working, weird.

Comment: Oh, now it's behaving the same as before again. This ver of firebase is not that stable